# Отсутствует оператор "=", соответствующий операндам

Tags: c++, ооп

Что тут не так? Почему я в `int main()` могу строке присвоить значение другой строки, а в конструкторе не могу?

```
class Player 
{
private:
    const std::string     name;
public:
    Player(std::string name)
    {
        this->name = name; // и вот здесь возникает ошибка
    }
}
```

Comment: У поля `name` имеется квалификатор `const` соответственно ничего присвоить ему нельзя, можно только инициализировать. *"я в int main() могу строке присвоить значение другой строки"* - в примере этого нет, значит такого не было

Comment: константную переменную можно инициализировать только в процессе конструирования. `Player(std::string name):name(name){}`

Comment: @user7860670 так я его инициализирую в конструкторе.

Comment: нет, инициализация полей в конструкторе происходит в списке инициализации и уже завершена при попадании внутрь фигурных скобок тела конструктора. `this->name = name;` является присваиванием.

Comment: `: name {"123"}` - это конструирование. А `this->name = "123";` - оператор присваивания.

Answer (score 0):

Представьте себе две строки:

```
const string s = "Hello";

s = "World";
```

Первая скомпилируется нормально, потому что это инициализация константной переменной, а вторая нет, так как это присваивание. У вас та же проблема: вы

```
this->name = name;
```

присваиваете, а не инициализируете константную строку. Инициализация в конструкторе делается после имени конструктора и двоеточия:

```
Player(std::string name):name(name){}
```

Вот здесь все будет правильно и никаких проблем. Разве что нет смысла делать копию строки для передачи конструктору, лучше передавать ссылку:

```
Player(const std::string& name):name(name){}
```